# Egoroff's theorem for infinite measure, but with compact convergence instead of uniform

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> I was reading Evans's "Measure theory and fine properties of functions" ($2$nd edition), and I saw the following statement in the proof of Theorem $6.11$:
>
> > for a sequence of measurable functions $\eta_k : B \to \mathbb{R}$, where $B$ is **some** measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which in the proof of the theorem is closed, but I do not think it is needed), assuming that $\eta_k \to 0$ pointwise as $k \to \infty$, then **by Egoroff's theorem**, we can find, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, a **closed** subset $C_\varepsilon \subset B$ so that $$\mathcal{L}^n(B \setminus C_\varepsilon) < \varepsilon,$$ and such that $\eta_k \to 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $C_\varepsilon$ (where $\mathcal{L}^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$).

My problem is that I do not know how Egoroff's theorem implies the above result. The theorem of Egoroff that is presented in Evans's book works only for sets of finite measure. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\sigma$-compact, we can slightly extend the classical theorem of Egoroff to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we are guaranteed the existence of some **measurable** subset $C_\varepsilon \subset B$ so that $\eta_k \to 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $C_\varepsilon$, and so that $$\mathcal{L}^n(B \setminus C_\varepsilon) < \varepsilon.$$

However, I do not see why we can choose $C_\varepsilon$ to be closed. If $B$ were to have finite Lebesgue measure, I suppose that inner regularity could help in choosing $C_\varepsilon$ to be closed; but, in the case that $B$ has infinite measure, inner regularity is not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually for any set $C$ you can find closed subset $D \subset C$ s.t. $\mu(C \setminus D) < \varepsilon$.

Let $A_n$ be some enumeration of unit cubes with integer coordinates (or actually any other countable family of measurable sets s.t. their union is the whole space, and every point has a neighbourhood that intersects only finitely many sets from our family).

Let $D_n$ be closed subset of $C \cap A_n$ s.t. $\mu(C \cap A_n \setminus D_n) < \varepsilon / 2^n$.
Let $D = \bigcup\limits_n D_n$.

$D$ is closed: assume $x$ is limit point of $D$, then it has neighbourhood $U_x$ that intersects only finite subfamiliy $\{D_{a_1}, \ldots, D_{a_n}\}$.
Then $x$ is also limit point for some of $D_{a_i}$, then $x \in D_{a_i}$ and so $x \in D$.

Also, $C \setminus D \subseteq \bigcup_n C \setminus D_n$, so $\mu(C \setminus D) \leq \sum\limits_n \mu(C \setminus D_n) = \varepsilon$.